# Parsing an xml file into R that has duplicate subscripts that gives duplicates their own rows?

Tags: r, xml

I have NIBRS (National Incident-Based Reporting System) xml data. The data gives a unique Report that has incidents and offenses attached. For each report there is one incident, that lists crucial date-time/location data. However, for each report, there can be multiple offenses (for example, an assault where there is also a drug violation).

I can pull the data into R using xmlParse and then ldply(xmlToList(x),data.frame). However, this provides the data in a wide format, which means each report lists out the offenses on the same line. Since each offense has it's own child nodes, the wide file can be hundreds of columns long if there are multiple offenses. What I need is for each Offense node to have it's own row in R, but still keeps the necessary incident/Report info on each line.

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)
x <- xmlParse("myXMLfile.xml")
ldply(xmlToList(x),data.frame) ** this gives me wide format data
xmlToDataFrame(x) ** this gives me the error "duplicate subscripts for columns"
```

> Example

What I need:

```
Report 1 - Incident 1 - Incident 1 Info - Offense 1 - Offense 1 info
Report 1 - Incident 1 - Incident 1 Info - Offense 2 - Offense 2 info
Report 2 - Incident 1 - Incident 1 Info - Offense 1 - Offense 1 info
Report 2 - Incident 1 - Incident 1 Info - Offense 2 - Offense 2 info
Report 2 - Incident 1 - Incident 1 Info - Offense 3 - Offense 3 info
```

What I get:

```
Report 1 - Incident 1 - Incident 1 Info - Offense 1 - Offense 1 info - Offense 2 - Offense 2 info
Report 2 - Incident 1 - Incident 1 Info - Offense 1 - Offense 1 info - Offense 2 - Offense 2 info - Offense 3 - Offense 3 info
```

XML data:

```
<nibrs:Submission>
<nibrs:Report>
 <nibrs:ReportHeader>
  <nibrs:NIBRSReportCategoryCode>GROUP A INCIDENT REPORT</nibrs:NIBRSReportCategoryCode>
  <nibrs:ReportActionCategoryCode>I</nibrs:ReportActionCategoryCode>
  <nibrs:ReportDate><nc:YearMonthDate>2019-06</nc:YearMonthDate> 
  </nibrs:ReportDate>
  <nibrs:ReportingAgency><j:OrganizationAugmentation> 
  <j:OrganizationORIIdentification> 
  <nc:IdentificationID>AA0951111</nc:IdentificationID> 
  </j:OrganizationORIIdentification></j:OrganizationAugmentation> 
  </nibrs:ReportingAgency>
 </nibrs:ReportHeader>
 <nc:Incident s:id="I-2144711304">
  <nc:ActivityIdentification><nc:IdentificationID>18-00000</nc:IdentificationID></nc:ActivityIdentification>
  <nc:ActivityDate><nc:DateTime>2018-09-19T10:00:00</nc:DateTime> 
  </nc:ActivityDate>
  <moibrs:IncidentLatitude>30.00000</moibrs:IncidentLatitude>
  <moibrs:IncidentLongitude>-90.00000</moibrs:IncidentLongitude>
 </nc:Incident>
 <j:Offense s:id="O-2144711304-35A">
  <moibrs:OffenseUCRCode>35A</moibrs:OffenseUCRCode> 
  <nibrs:CategoryCode>P</nibrs:CategoryCode> 
  <j:BiasMotivationCode>NONE</j:BiasMotivationCode>
  <j:OffenseFactor><j:OffenseFactorCode>N</j:OffenseFactorCode>  
  </j:OffenseFactor>
  <j:OffenseEntryPoint>  
  <j:PassagePointMethodCode>N</j:PassagePointMethodCode> 
  </j:OffenseEntryPoint>
  <j:OffenseAttemptedIndicator>false</j:OffenseAttemptedIndicator>
 </j:Offense>
  <j:Offense s:id="O-2144711304-520">
  <moibrs:OffenseUCRCode>520</moibrs:OffenseUCRCode>
  <nibrs:CategoryCode>P</nibrs:CategoryCode> 
  <j:BiasMotivationCode>NONE</j:BiasMotivationCode>
  <j:OffenseFactor><j:OffenseFactorCode>N</j:OffenseFactorCode>  
  </j:OffenseFactor>
  <j:OffenseEntryPoint>  
  <j:PassagePointMethodCode>N</j:PassagePointMethodCode> 
  </j:OffenseEntryPoint>
  <j:OffenseForce><j:ForceCategoryCode>12</j:ForceCategoryCode>  
  </j:OffenseForce>
  <j:OffenseAttemptedIndicator>false</j:OffenseAttemptedIndicator>
 </j:Offense>
 <nc:Location s:id="L-2144711304">
  <nibrs:LocationCategoryCode>20</nibrs:LocationCategoryCode>
 </nc:Location>
 <nc:Substance s:id="PR-2144617767-6">
   <nc:ItemStatus><cjis:ItemStatusCode>SEIZED</cjis:ItemStatusCode>  
   </nc:ItemStatus>
   <j:ItemCategory>10</j:ItemCategory>
   <j:DrugCategoryCode>E</j:DrugCategoryCode>
   <nc:SubstanceQuantityMeasure>
   <nc:MeasureDecimalValue>2</nc:MeasureDecimalValue>
   <j:SubstanceUnitCode>GM</j:SubstanceUnitCode>
   </nc:SubstanceQuantityMeasure>
  </nc:Substance>
 </nibrs:Report>
 </nibrs:Submission>
```

Comment: In your sample code, are you using the `ddply` and `XML` packages? It's nice to be explicit. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm using  plyr and XML packages.

Comment: which command assigns xml data to x? Is it xmlParse(filename)?

Comment: Yes. x <- xmlParse("myXMLfile.xml")

Comment: Your XML uses namespace prefixes (`nibrs`, `nc`, `j`, etc.) that you do not show definitions. Namespaces are very important in parsing XML. Please include the `xmlns:nibrs=...` and others. Usually they are on the *root* node. Otherwise, this is not a well-formed XML file and should fail in parsing.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the xml the federal government gives me, I don’t know how to make it well-formed. I’ve worked with xml before, but this one is too difficult for me to figure out. What do you mean by include the xmlns:nibrs=...? Sorry.

Comment: Are you sure *nibrs:Submission* is root or is there a node above it? Maybe you forgotten to post it?

Comment: nibrs:Submission is the first and last thing on the xml document. Here is a link to an FBI example. [link](https://www.fbi.gov/file-repository/ucr/ucr-2019-1-nibrs-xml-iepd.zip/view)